# Will this 3-phase 208Y/120 setup work

Tags: transformer, three-phase, single-phase

OKAY...electrician I had out recommended the following setup to supply 3-phase wye 208/120v off of 240V single-phase. My device is pulling 30 amps, and my entire load is about 15KVA. It's impossible to get an exact load number due to a number of VFD's that are converting three-phase into single-phase to run motors inside my unit. The best approximation is 12-15KVA. Btw, my panel can supply 100 amps.

1. 240V single-phase--> into Buck & Boost Step-Down Transformer (Larson)--> out comes 208v single-phase
2. 208v single-phase--> into 4.5HP static phase converter (Larson)--> out comes 208vD three-phase
3. 208vD three-phase--> Square D Sorgel 15KVA 40 Amp 3-phase transformer 208vD to 208Y/120...magic?

Does this seem reasonable? Will the harmonic distortion be terrible? I'm running some sensitive electronics and really, really don't want to screw anything up. For a cost of $5,000, I'm hoping this solution is sound.

Thanks in advance for the input.

Comment: Ask the electrician. Ask Larson. Get links to technical details for Larson equipment and each connected electronic load and ask here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for recommendations about compatibility of interconnected equipment with only a vague description. We are not technical support for any products let alone what is vaguely described in this question.

Comment: is there some reason why toy can't do the wye-delta and the voltage conversion in the same step?

Comment: @CharlesCowie Wow. You're helpful. I wonder why I didn't think of doing any of those things....the question is hardly vague. I include my load, the equipment, etc. I ask about compatibility between single-phase converters and 3-phase transformers. Harmonics...easy question. I just asked my electrical engineering professor and he promptly gave me my reply (without being asinine and useless). Keep in mind I did not ask for your feedback, so no I do not treat anyone as technical support. For that matter, I would sooner go to the Apple Genius bar for this question than you.

Comment: @Jasen Thank you! Great comment. My electrical engineering professor just confirmed this is the best way to go. I appreciate your input. I hadn't thought about converting straight to delta-wye and then routing through a transformer for conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Seems very complex. A more typical approach for single-to-3phase is to use a rotary converter. I bet that's a lot cheaper than $5k.

Here's a whole list of them, from 1HP all the way up to 80HP (55KW). The most expensive one is less than $4800. See here: http://www.phaseconverter.com/#Rotary-Converter

Comment: you still need to reduce the voltage down to 208 and provide a neutral.

Comment: The page is shown as an example. Unfortunately... the links seem to be non functional. Typical config is in fact 240 1-ph in / 208 3-ph out. Will need to add a delta-to-wye transformer to get a neutral.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you intend to supply with 208V 3 phase, if it is only 3 phase motor the best solution is frequency inverter for about 2000 us dolars. But if you have a complex device running on 110 phase to neutral and 208V 3 phase you can use a type of UPS that has US standard output or split supply so to drive motor(s) with frequency inverter and other equipment with UPS. 
For proper answer more specific info is necessary.